# react-native create app hangs while create

Tags: react-native, create-react-app

I use react-native with actual version and have tried to create a simple project. But while trying to create it by using

`expo init AwesomeProject`

the whole process hangs.

I have tried to look for a solution by searching on the internet but without any luck.

The error could be seen in the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I see that you are using a Administrator PowerShell please try in normal command prompt without administrative privileges

Comment: You might get more help on this with an Expo tag.  It doesn't seem like you're using CRA or RN.

Answer (score 0):

That error generally means that a file is being accessed by two different things at 'around' the same time. And 90% of those times it is because of an anti-virus or similar.

Its a permission error, so my advice, try to do it after a fresh reboot and boot the powershell as admin, disable antivirus etc..

If still does not work reinstall nodejs/npm.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience. The project gets created using React-native. When you try to run it, the 'Metro' interface comes up. There is an android phone on the USB drive which has previously been used to run Android Studio created projects successfully. However, on the command shell the app hangs in Metro.

While trying to run the project from Android Studio snow cat, there are build errors (red) in the App manifest file and there is this exception.
Build failed due to java.lang.NullPointerException

Installed expo-cli (C:\Reactive-native>npm install -g expo-cli). The app fails to run and hangs on the connected Android phone(Samsung 21) using the Expo Go client. This client has no problem having been tested in Snackbar.

I have a question in the Expo forum and probably someone will answer!